# Two CSS classes on one div not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this css from bootstrap.min:

```
.rew {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 1050px;
}

.rew2 {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: auto;
}
```

And my div like this (I've red examples from question and answer in stackoverflow):

```
<div class="rew rew2">
content.....
</div>
```

The (**rew2**) it's for responsived css, but before that I was wrote the css on my *responsive* css file, but it's not working the "**div tag**" always calls css from *bootstrap.min* css file. So I wrote two classes in the *bootstrap.min* css file, but not working also. The "**div**" tag only called the "**rew**" class and the "**rew2**" was ignored.

******** The class on responsive css file was deleted and I wrote the class on bootstrapmin css file

The differences it's only on *width*, if the site opened from desktop it would have *1050px* width, and for the responsive (opened from smartphone) it will automatically adjust the template with the smartphone screen as "*auto*".

*Huft...I'm so confused why it's not working. I need help from you guys.

Thank you,

Best regards,

Kris

Comment: Um, the last one is going to win... And the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) matters.

Comment: Make your selector more specific, so it is overruling the other style sheets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you customize bootstraps `.css` file on your own? Just create your own rules and attach them to your `div`.

CSS stylings are always used one by one. So if you, for example, include your `bootstrap.min.css` file before your own styling rules, your own ones would overwrite all bootstrap stylings.

In other words:
First of all include `bootstrap.min.css`, then your own `.css` file.

Let's assume you've got this markup

```
<div class="foo bar"> </div>
```

You could style it through the 2 classes `foo` and `bar`.

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}

.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```

Using this would end up in the blue color, according to the declared order.

Let's even try to be a bit more specific.
You can also overwrite rules by using some more complex selectors.

```
.foo.bar {
  color: black;
}
```

The above code would overwrite both of the previously defined rules, because they are '**stronger**' selectors than a simple single-class selector.

**Conclusion**
If you want to overwrite bootstraps styling, try to stick to the order. If bootstrap uses some complex selectors and your custom ones won't trigger, try to use a bit more complex ones. Look [here](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/) to learn more about complex selectors.

A little hint at the end:
Try to avoid **`!important`**! A rule, declared as `!important`, will overwrite all other rules, regardless of whatever you have declared up before.

Comment: Thank you...thank you...all my life I just realized that the css file order was affecting the template output on screen, I just know the time I've read your answer...Lol...I didn't know that before. And yes I just make my own style rules...haha...Thank you so much. Thank you guys....you all the best. Best Regards.....Oh yea..almost forget, and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't customize bootstrap.min.css create your own css file, In that you can write your own css as you need.As per you requirement include media query for smartphone in that give width: 100%; for that element.